# Rounded Radar Chart in Victory Native

Tags: react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

I'm trying to create a radar chart in `Victory Native` but I need the edges of the radar to be rounded.

The chart provided looks like this:

[image: Text]

while I need to make it look like this:

[image: Text]

Ideally I would just add lineTension in the style like so:

```
<VictoryGroup 
     colorScale={["gold", "orange", "tomato"]}
     style={{ data: { fillOpacity: 0.2, strokeWidth: 2, lineTension: 0.7 } }}
 >
    {this.state.data.map((data, i) => {
       return <VictoryArea key={i} data={data}/>;
    })}
</VictoryGroup>
```

But that doesn't do anything.

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hi @Adam, I'm facing exactly the opposite issue, this is the [official example](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/radar-chart/) that I'm using, in here VictoryPolarAxis is being used to render circular grid and I'm unable to change it to a polygonal one. Can you please let me know how you rendered the polygonal one. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `interpolation` prop on your VictoryArea component with these available polar chart options:

> "basis", "cardinal", "catmullRom", "linear"

[interpolation prop in Victory documentation](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-area/#interpolation)

```
<VictoryArea key={i} data={data} interpolation="cardinal" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Saved me loads of trouble bro, NOSTROMO on da OVERFLOW DO